# Very slow function, is there a faster way? (using jQuery 1.4.2)

Tags: jquery, performance, html-table

The following function needs at least 3 seconds to run (on 500 table rows). Is it possible to make this function faster?

```
function prepareTable() {
    var groupIndex = 0;
    $("#row tbody tr").each(function(index) {
    // each row gets a unique id
    // remove default css styles for table rows
    // read out hidden value, that stores if row is a group
    var group = $(this).attr('id', 'node-'+index).removeClass("odd event").find('td :hidden').attr('value');
    // if it is a group, add special styles to row and remember row index
    if (group == 'true') {
        groupIndex = index;
        $(this).addClass('odd').find("td:first")
            .mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).parent().addClass("swGroupLink");
            })
            .mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass("swGroupLink");
        });
    } else {
        // make all following rows to children of the previous group found
        $(this).addClass('even child-of-node-' + groupIndex);
    }   
    });
}
```

Comment: all 500 table rows are visible or are you using pagination?

Comment: i'm also using pagination. thx for the hint...

Comment: then you can do processing on visible part of table only.

Comment: I'm doing that, but sometimes customer want to have 500 rows on one page ;-). Now I'm trying if it is possible in bearable waiting time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest two improvements:

- Cache `DOM References`
- Work at your table **offline**

**Example**

```
function prepareTable() {
   var groupIndex = 0;
   var $mytable = $('#row'),
       $parent  = $mytable.parent();

   $mytable = $mytable.detach();

   $mytable.find('tr').each(function(index) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var group = $this.attr('id', 'node-'+index).removeClass("odd event").find('td :hidden').attr('value');
// if it is a group, add special styles to row and remember row index
   if (group == 'true') {
       groupIndex = index;
       $this.addClass('odd').find("td:first")
           .mouseenter(function() {
               $this.parent().addClass("swGroupLink");
           })
           .mouseleave(function() {
               $this.parent().removeClass("swGroupLink");
       });
   } else {
       // make all following rows to children of the previous group found
       $this.addClass('even child-of-node-' + groupIndex);
   }   
   });

   $parent.append($mytable);
}
```

I added a variable `$this` which caches `$(this)` in your `.each()` loop. I also added `$mytable` and `$parent`. `$mytable` stores the `#row` element and `$parent` stores the parent-node from `#row`. That is because I remove the whole element from the DOM, do the work and re-attach it to the parent.

Test environment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/2C6fB/4/

If that is still too slow, you have other options here. First, look if you can split the loop into smaller pieces. You can optimize that like a lot by using `asychronous` callbacks, for instance, `setTimeout`. That can be a tricky business and I would need to know your code in more detail, but in general you might just want to wrap your whole loop into single `setTimeout()` functions. Example -> http://www.jsfiddle.net/2C6fB/5/

This ensures that the browser won't "hang" while operating. But of course this took a little bit longer to complete the whole task.

Comment: Your optimization sound very good for me. Unfortunately the function is now about 20 percent slower :-( 
(Tested with Firebug and Google Chrome Developer Tools)

Comment: @Steven: That sounds almost impossible. I'm setting up a quick test environment.

Comment: @Steven: As I expected, my version is about 50% faster than the old one. See http://www.jsfiddle.net/2C6fB/2/
You need to open firebug/chrome console to see the results. Just comment the bottom lines out/in to test the different functions.

Comment: Weird! Here a screenshot of my results on the real page: http://yfrog.com/mrtimerp

Comment: @Steven: I added another solution in my answer, you'll maybe find that more usefull. But I wouldn't use that as "universal" solution. You still should think over your loop there, where you can split it into sub-problems and optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

you can take mouseenter and mouseleave outside with live event, so that it will not execute with prepareTable function and you can put it in document ready function.

```
 $("#row tbody tr td.trueInPrepareTable")
  .live("mouseenter", function(event){      
               $(this).parent().addClass("swGroupLink");    
    }).live("mouseleave", function(event){      
               $(this).parent().removeClass("swGroupLink");    
    });
```

instead of fetching group value from hidden field,  put this value in the rel,rev or title attribute.

```
    function prepareTableEdit() {
                var groupIndex = 0;
                $("#row tbody tr").each(function(index) {
                     groupIndex = index;
                     $(this).attr('id', 'node-'+ groupIndex ).removeClass("odd even");
                    if($(this).attr('rel') == 'true')
                    {                           
                        $(this).addClass('odd').find("td:first").addClass('trueInPrepareTable');                      }
                    else
                    {
                         $(this).addClass('even child-of-node-' + groupIndex).find("td:first").removeClass('trueInPrepareTable');  
                    }
                });

 }
```

check out http://www.jsfiddle.net/raBGq/

Comment: nice idea, but almost the same execution time (-100 to -200 ms)

Comment: check out http://www.jsfiddle.net/raBGq/. it took 160 ms to run, much faster as compared to yours. You need to open firebug console for viewing results.

Comment: your new version ignores "child-of-node-<id>"

Answer (score -1):

i guess the find is the one where all the times goes lost.

can you not make a selector of it in stead of a find. what's the HTML?

Comment: find needs 80ms for all 500 rows